# C# Compile Error

Tags: c#

```
int[] ddfv = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().Split('_').Select(part => int.Parse(part, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer)).ToArray();
```

error : there is no .Select in String [] :(

there is a value like "1_2" I need to save 1 and 2 as integer values :)

Comment: break it up into multiple lines. i would seriously complain to a team lead if i saw you write this one lined monstrosity in production code. Breaking it up will help A:solve your compiler problem. because it will help with- B: Readbility. C: Allow debugging each intermediate step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select is an extension method, defined in the `System.Linq` namespace.

The reason for the error is probably one of these:

- you are missing the reference to the assembly `System.Core`
- you are missing the using directive for Linq (`using System.Linq;`)
- you are not using .NET 3.x

Answer (score 1):

int[] value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().Split('_');
in the above "value" contains all split values, use index to fetch respective values
ex:
if DropDownList selected values is course_name_123
so i want only character before _  use the first line code and value[0] contains ur new data